# Get object filter to work without error in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

I have the following filter that works in jsfiddle (and in a stackoverflow snippit) but it won't work when I paste and run it verbatim in google apps script. I'm getting an error message "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object (line 94)" - line 94 is `if (Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {`. Then if I check the log, it DOES log the correct output, but I still want to know why I'm getting this pesky error.

log:

```
[20-10-26 22:13:29:611 EDT] fruits: strawberry
[20-10-26 22:13:29:613 EDT] vegetables: lettuce,radish
[20-10-26 22:13:29:614 EDT] pasta: spaghetti,rigatoni,lasagna,fettuccine
[20-10-26 22:13:29:633 EDT] TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at filtered(test:94:16)
```

Also, I would like the output to be in the form of "lettuce, radish" with a space between them but if I make it `.join(", ")` it doesn't do anything.

```
var obj = {
  "c4ecb": {"id": [3]},
  "a4269": {"id": [34,36]},
  "d76fa": {"id": [54,55,60,61]},
  "58cb5": {"id": [67]}
}

var response = 
    [{
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "c4ecb",
          "name": "fruits",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "strawberry",
              "id": 3
            },
            {
              "label": "apple",
              "id": 4
            },
            {
              "label": "pineapple",
              "id": 5
            },
            {
              "label": "Other",
              "id": 31
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "a4269",
          "name": "vegetables",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "lettuce",
              "id": 34
            },
            {
              "label": "cucumber",
              "id": 35
            },
            {
              "label": "radish",
              "id": 36
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "d76fa",
          "name": "pasta",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "spaghetti",
              "id": 54
            },
            {
              "label": "rigatoni",
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "label": "linguine",
              "id": 56
            },
            {
              "label": "lasagna",
              "id": 60
            },
            {
              "label": "fettuccine",
              "id": 61
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    }];
 
 
 function filteredLabelsAsString(obj_key, obj, content=response) {
    // sanity check: obj must contain obj_key
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {
        return content.filter((item) => {
            // filter content using value of obj_key
            return item.data[0].key == obj_key;
        }).map((item) => {
            // item : { success: true, data: [] }
            // map over options array
            return item.data[0].options.map((opt) => {
                // option : {id, label}
                // return the label if the id is in the obj object's list
                if (obj[item.data[0].key].id.includes(opt.id))
                    return opt.label;
            }).filter((label) => {
                // filter out empty items
                return label !== undefined;
            });
        }).join(",");
    }
    // if obj does not contain obj_key return empty string
    return "";
}   
console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj));  
console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj));
console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj));
```

Comment: From `it won't work when I paste and run it verbatim in google apps script.`, in your situation, I thought that you might have directly run the function `filteredLabelsAsString`. In that case, such error occurs. When you want to run your script, for example, how about putting whole script to `###` of `function sample() {###}` and running the function `sample()`? By this, you can see the result values at the console.

Comment: I did directly run the function `filteredLabelsAsString`. When I comment out the body of the function, the log now just reads `[20-10-26 22:42:06:148 EDT] fruits: undefined
[20-10-26 22:42:06:150 EDT] vegetables: undefined
[20-10-26 22:42:06:152 EDT] pasta: undefined`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason of your issue is to directly run the function `filteredLabelsAsString`. So when you tested my proposal, what result did you obtain? Or, when you run the function of `function sample() {console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj)); console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj)); console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj));}` and run `sample()`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking regarding the sample function. You want me to comment out the filteredLablesAsString function, and then run the following function? `function sample() {console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj)); console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj)); console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj));}` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. By my poor English skill, I confused you. I deeply apologize for this. In order to run your script by Google Apps Script and retrieve the result values, I proposed the modified script as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When you put the script in your question to the script editor, and run `filteredLabelsAsString`, `obj_key` and `obj` are `undefined`. By this, an error of `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` occurs.

  - I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In order to retrieve the result values using Google Apps Script, it is required to give the arguments to the function `filteredLabelsAsString`.

  - But, in your situation, I thought that it might be suitable that `response` is not the global variable.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and run the function of `sample()`. By this, you can see the result values at the log.

```
function filteredLabelsAsString(obj_key, obj, content=response) { // or function filteredLabelsAsString(obj_key, obj, content) {
    // sanity check: obj must contain obj_key
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {
        return content.filter((item) => {
            // filter content using value of obj_key
            return item.data[0].key == obj_key;
        }).map((item) => {
            // item : { success: true, data: [] }
            // map over options array
            return item.data[0].options.map((opt) => {
                // option : {id, label}
                // return the label if the id is in the obj object's list
                if (obj[item.data[0].key].id.includes(opt.id))
                    return opt.label;
            }).filter((label) => {
                // filter out empty items
                return label !== undefined;
            });
        }).join(",");
    }
    // if obj does not contain obj_key return empty string
    return "";
}

// Please run this function.
function sample() {
  var obj = {
    "c4ecb": {"id": [3]},
    "a4269": {"id": [34,36]},
    "d76fa": {"id": [54,55,60,61]},
    "58cb5": {"id": [67]}
  }
  
  var response = 
      [{
        "success": true,
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "c4ecb",
            "name": "fruits",
            "options": [
              {
                "label": "strawberry",
                "id": 3
              },
              {
                "label": "apple",
                "id": 4
              },
              {
                "label": "pineapple",
                "id": 5
              },
              {
                "label": "Other",
                "id": 31
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "success": true,
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "a4269",
            "name": "vegetables",
            "options": [
              {
                "label": "lettuce",
                "id": 34
              },
              {
                "label": "cucumber",
                "id": 35
              },
              {
                "label": "radish",
                "id": 36
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "success": true,
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "d76fa",
            "name": "pasta",
            "options": [
              {
                "label": "spaghetti",
                "id": 54
              },
              {
                "label": "rigatoni",
                "id": 55
              },
              {
                "label": "linguine",
                "id": 56
              },
              {
                "label": "lasagna",
                "id": 60
              },
              {
                "label": "fettuccine",
                "id": 61
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      }];
  console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj, response));  
  console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj, response));
  console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj, response));
}
```

#### Result:

When the function `sample()` of above script is run the following values can be seen at the log.

```
fruits: strawberry
vegetables: lettuce,radish
pasta: spaghetti,rigatoni,lasagna,fettuccine
```

#### Note:

When `obj` and `response` are used as the global variable, the following script can be also used.

```js
var obj = {
  "c4ecb": {"id": [3]},
  "a4269": {"id": [34,36]},
  "d76fa": {"id": [54,55,60,61]},
  "58cb5": {"id": [67]}
}

var response = 
    [{
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "c4ecb",
          "name": "fruits",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "strawberry",
              "id": 3
            },
            {
              "label": "apple",
              "id": 4
            },
            {
              "label": "pineapple",
              "id": 5
            },
            {
              "label": "Other",
              "id": 31
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "a4269",
          "name": "vegetables",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "lettuce",
              "id": 34
            },
            {
              "label": "cucumber",
              "id": 35
            },
            {
              "label": "radish",
              "id": 36
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "d76fa",
          "name": "pasta",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "spaghetti",
              "id": 54
            },
            {
              "label": "rigatoni",
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "label": "linguine",
              "id": 56
            },
            {
              "label": "lasagna",
              "id": 60
            },
            {
              "label": "fettuccine",
              "id": 61
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    }];
 
 
 function filteredLabelsAsString(obj_key, obj, content=response) {
    // sanity check: obj must contain obj_key
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {
        return content.filter((item) => {
            // filter content using value of obj_key
            return item.data[0].key == obj_key;
        }).map((item) => {
            // item : { success: true, data: [] }
            // map over options array
            return item.data[0].options.map((opt) => {
                // option : {id, label}
                // return the label if the id is in the obj object's list
                if (obj[item.data[0].key].id.includes(opt.id))
                    return opt.label;
            }).filter((label) => {
                // filter out empty items
                return label !== undefined;
            });
        }).join(",");
    }
    // if obj does not contain obj_key return empty string
    return "";
}

function sample() {
  console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj));  
  console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj));
  console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj));
}
```